# As per CAP theorem which category does memcached fall into?

Tags: database, performance, memcached, availability, cap-theorem

I am planning to use memcached DB.
As per my requirement High performance(speed) and availability is by highest priority.(Consistency can be traded of to some extent)
please suggest be with a proper DB.

I am following [CAP Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx8h0.png).

By category i mean CA or CP or AP as shown in the below diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [official website](http://memcached.org/about) Memcached is more concerned about Consistency and Availability i.e., CA category.